# Checkstyle for ColdFusion?

Tags: eclipse, coldfusion, eclipse-plugin, checkstyle

Is there some kind of Checkstyle plug-in for Eclipse available for ColdFusion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There aren't really any coding specifications for ColdFusion.  Sean Corfield wrote one for Macromedia's internal development departments that some folks use, but there really isn't a set of coding conventions and rules that the community adheres to.  Thus, there is no plugin to test that your code follows those rules.

That said, if you have standards that you prefer/enforce in your company or team, then you can use the code formatter in ColdFusion Builder 2 ([still in public beta, at this time](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/coldfusionbuilder2/)) to quickly check/update source files.

You set the formatting guidelines in the Eclipse preferences, and then you can run the formatter from the menu: **Edit > Format** (Keyboard shortcut: cmd/control + shift + F)

Comment: good point Adam.  I thought of that shortly after hitting submit :)

Comment: Unfortunately we use CFEclipse which does provide minimal formatting, but doesn't check variable naming conventions or the use of tabs instead of spaces, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I search around a bit for cf specific Checkstyle tool, no luck. I think since CF is a tagging language as much as a scripting language, it lags behind in tools like this.  You could check out the coldfusion specific eclipse plugin, it may have some of its own type checkstyle functionality.

http://cfeclipse.org/

Answer (score 0):

Hoping this is still relevant to someone...

Long time ago, I've tried an approach using checkstyle regexp tags.
I wrote a blog post, check if there is any useful hint:

http://rcastagno.blogspot.it/2009/09/checkstyle-50-regexps-and-eclipse.html

Answer (score 0):

There is a static code checker, written in ColdFusion, FOR ColdFusion. see https://github.com/wellercs/CodeChecker. There is also a linter that can plug in to Eclipse or ColdFusion Builder, called CFLint. See https://github.com/cflint/CFLint for that tool.
So CodeChecker is a stand-alone application and CFLint may be used, as I remember, stand-alone or as a plug-in to a number of IDEs.
You can easily add rules and guides to CodeChecker, I haven't tried with CFLint.